# OnInput не работает из-за двух Form, какое решение?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Здравствуйте.
Есть логика в OnInput, но из-за двух тэгов FORM которые, к сожалению, удалить нельзя, заюзать OnInput невозможно, **как правильно решить задачу?** 
ПС. Убрать один form - не подходит, т.к. схематически код недолжен измениться.
ПС2. Можно ли переписать код таким образом, чтобы введя цифры в input считалось и показывалось в  либо ?

[ссылка](https://jsfiddle.net/dphrc1y2/)

```html
<form id="neded">
  <input id="3" oninput="var v = this.value; this.form.a.value = isNaN(v) ? '' : (v * 1.5).toFixed (2); var b = this.value; this.form.b.value = isNaN(b) ? '' : (v * 1.05).toFixed (2)" value="0">
</form>

<form id="calk">
  <input type="text" name="a">

  <input type="text" name="b">
</form>
```

Comment: из всех 3х input и динамический выводилось в div сумма?

Comment: нет, можно оставить только один input (для того, чтобы ввести число) и чтобы выводилось в <div> два значения (которые считают в логике).

Comment: не понял ничего...

Comment: грубо говоря, вместо <input type="text" name="a"> и  <input type="text" name="b"> необходимо выводить значения в  <div> и оставить только один инпут <input id="3" oninput="var v = this.value; this.form.a.value = isNaN(v) ? '' : (v * 1.5).toFixed (2); var b = this.value; this.form.b.value = isNaN(b) ? '' : (v * 1.05).toFixed (2)" value="0">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то должно получится нечто такое :

```js
function fn(that) {
  var v = that.value;

  document.querySelector('input[name="a"]').value = isNaN(v) ? '' : (v * 1.5).toFixed(2);
  document.querySelector('input[name="b"]').value = isNaN(v) ? '' : (v * 1.05).toFixed(2);
};
```

```html
<form id="neded">
  <input id="3" oninput="fn(this);" value="0">
</form>

<form id="calk">
  <input type="text" name="a">

  <input type="text" name="b">
</form>
```

Пример с `div` :

```js
function fn(that) {
  var v = that.value;
  document.querySelector('div[name="a"]').innerHTML = isNaN(v) ? '' : (v * 1.5).toFixed(2);
  document.querySelector('div[name="b"]').innerHTML = isNaN(v) ? '' : (v * 1.05).toFixed(2);
};
```

```css
div[name="a"],
div[name="b"] {
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form id="neded">
  <input id="3" oninput="fn(this);" value="0">
</form>

<form id="calk">
  <div name="a"></div>
  <div name="b"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте. Спасибо. А как-то можно вместо input A и B выводить значения в <div>?

Comment: Конечно можно, нужно получить див, и использовать его свойство `innerHTML` чтобы вписать внутрь чтото

Comment: А Как правильно выполнить данную задачу? Смогли бы помочь?
 Пожалуйста.

Comment: @Pubat дополнил ответ

Comment: Спасибо большое!